# How to use Generating Function to find sum of series?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

How to use generating function to find the sum of series
$1.2.3+2.3.4+3.4.5...+(r-1).r.(r+1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular problem, we don't really need to use generating function.
We can use the fact
$$(r-1)r(r+1) = \frac14\left((r-1)r(r+1)(r+2) - (r-2)(r-1)r(r+1) \right)$$
and the sum is a telescoping one.

If one insists of using generating function, we can start from the OGF for constant sequence $1$:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k = \frac{1}{1-z}$$
For any positive integer $n$, multiply both sides by $z^n$ and differentiate $n$ times, we get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\prod_{i=1}^n (k+i)\right) z^k
= \frac{d^n}{dz^n}\left[\frac{z^n}{1-z}\right]
= \frac{d^n}{dz^n}\left[\frac{1}{1-z} - ( 1 + z + \cdots + z^{n-1} ) \right]
= \frac{n!}{(1-z)^{n+1}}
$$
Mulitply boths sides by $\frac{1}{1-z}$. Expand coefficients in LHS as a 
[Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product), we get

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{\ell=0}^k \prod_{i=1}^n(\ell+i)\right)z^k
= \frac{n!}{(1-z)^{n+2}} = \frac{1}{n+1}\frac{d^{n+1}}{dz^{n+1}}\left[\frac{1}{1-z}\right]
= \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} (k+i)\right) z^k
$$
Compare coefficients of $z^k$ on both sides, we get
$$\sum_{\ell=0}^k \left(\prod_{i=1}^n (\ell+i)\right) = 
\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} (k+i)\right)
$$
For $n = 3$ and $k = r-2$, this reduces to

$$1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 +2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 +3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 + \cdots + (r-1) r (r+1)
= \frac14 (r-1)r(r+1)(r+2)$$

Comment: We could even notice that $(i-1)i(i+1)=i^3-i$ and the summation becomes more than trivial. Cheers.